# How to change body text for pandoc template?

Tags: color, pandoc

I'm looking for a way to change the color of the text and text headings (p, H1, H2, H3) within a pandoc document that is using the [Eisvogel](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template) theme.

I'm aware following method can be applied functional, to change text color:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

This is a sample text in black.
\textcolor{blue}{This is a sample text in blue.}

\end{document}
```

**However, how can I define a more general template for the text and headings/subheadings mentioned above?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just edit pandoc template file `eisvogel.tex`, it contains all the definitions.

Comment: Yes, but where is the body color and section header color defined? I only found how to change the color on the title page, and how to change the font family.

Comment: Around line 656. The `\addtokomafont` mechanism is used. Just add the definitions you need. KOMA is very well documented, so take a look at the manual, to find out how fonts and colors are handled: https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script